# Add a dynamic jquery a href into a dynamic jquery div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created an `<a>` tag dynamically and a `<div>` dynamically. I want the `<a>` to be the child of the `<div>` and finally add the div to it's parent. Following is the code:

```
var contentLinkWithImage = $('<img />', {
            src:'images/cg/story1.jpg',
            width:'300',
            height:'250',
            class:'img-responsive item_back_img'
        });

var contentLink = $('a', {
            href:'#',
            text:contentLinkWithImage
});

var div_Item = $('<div/>', {
            class: 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 portfolio-item',
            html : contentLink
});
```

Finally I am adding the `div_item` to a given parent div using the following:

`$('#myParentDiv').html(div_Item);`

The problem is I could only see the `div_Item` when rendered, not it's children. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show us what your final HTML should look like and how you are getting it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `append`

```
var div_Item = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 portfolio-item'

});
 div_Item.append(contentLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem with the image. You must declare the measurement for the width and height in css.

So, use like this;

```
var contentLinkWithImage = $('<img />', {
            src:'images/cg/story1.jpg',
            width:'300px',
            height:'250px',
            class:'img-responsive item_back_img'
        });
```